# How would dualistic schools of Vedanta (Vishistadvaitha and Dvaita) debate with a Buddhist?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, vishishtadvaita, dvaita, buddhism

As far as I know, Vishishtadvaitha and Dvaita base their arguments on Vedas.

As Buddhists reject the Vedas, how would the dualistic schools of Vedanta debate with Buddhists and establish Veda pramanya?

For Eg: just adreess the existence of soul.  Buddhists hold there is no soul. Vedantists hold there is soul. What is the proof according to Vedantists?

Comment: No one.........?

Comment: The question is too broad. It would be great if you could be specific about what specific argument or difference would you like to compare in the answers to your question.

Comment: @GokulNC just adreess the existence of soul.  Buddhists hold there is no soul. Vedantists hold there is soul. What is the proof according to Vedantists?

Comment: https://pdfbooks.ourhindi.com/vedant-mein-bouddha-sandarbh-by-dr-anamika-singh/  if you can read hindi, its a book on vedantas refutation of buddhisim, not necessarily Vishistadvaitic or dvaita viewpoint

Comment: @KrsnaDasa The link is dead

Answer (score -1):

I would like to write most probable refutation Buddhist doctrine by Vaishnavaism.

> Buddhists teach, that there are two types of arising (samudaya),
> namely external and internal. The external arising refers to things
> such as the earth, rivers, oceans and so on. These are made of four
> kinds of minute particles (paramāṇus) namely earthly, watery,  fiery,
> and windy types. The internal arising refers to mind (citta) and
> memory (caitya). This internal arising is made of five types of
> aggregates (pañca-skandha), namely form (rūpa), consciousness
> (vijñāna), sensation(vedanā), perception (samjñā) and mental
> impression (saṃskāra).

We first reject the theory of creation based on minute particles and aggregates. These elements cannot create the universe because according to Buddhism there is no agent
that puts them together. We also reject the possibility that the Buddha could fulfill
the role of cosmic agent, pointing out that according to Buddhist theory everything is momentary. If the cosmic agent were momentary, he could not have a desire for creation. The underlying assumption is that a momentary agent cannot have such a desire because to desire something requires the continued existence of the desiring agent. After rejecting what we perceive to be the Buddhist theory of creation, we now proceed to refute the Buddhist theory of causation, namely the doctrine of interdependent origination. According to this Buddhist doctrine, ignorance (avidya) is the ultimate cause of our samsaric experience.

We quote

> उत्तरोत्पादे च पूर्वनिरोधात् (Brahma Sutra 2.2.20)

Which means "Ignorance and so on do not explain causality" because the preceding one is destroyed when the subsequent one arises.” The Buddhist theory cannot explain causality:
(1) since a momentary (kṣaṇika) cause cannot be the material cause due to the fact that it is not connected to the effect that exists in a later moment, (2) since only a cause that is connected to an effect can be the material cause, (3) since an effect cannot arise without that [i.e. a cause connected to the effect], and (4) because with the destruction of such cause the connection [between the cause and the effect] is not explained. If everything is momentary then there is no causality possible because there cannot be any contact between a cause and an effect. After refuting the Buddhist theories of creation and causality, we now move on to state that the goal of human life according to Buddhism is not worth pursuing.

The desire for the goal of human life, which is eternal and which  has a single essence, does not arise for a self that is momentary. This is because  such a self has the nature of complete suffering as it is afflicted with great calamity and because there is no self of its own after its [i.e. suffering’s] cessation. To explain, no one desires the destruction of the self. The Buddhist theory of momentariness amounts to the destruction of the self. No one wishes to attain such a state. The goal of human life, which is eternal and which has a single essence is to attain Lord Narayana who is ocean of innumerable auspicious attributes which are intrinsic to His nature and cannot be surpassed — some of them being; omniscience, omnipotence, sovereignty, energy, creative-potency and glory. He is a repository of limitless perfections such as radiance, beauty, fragrance, tenderness, pervading sweetness and youthfulness.

> There are four types of meditations which Buddhists practise, namely
> meditation on one’s characteristics (svalakṣaṇa), on momentariness
> (kṣaṇika), on suffering (duḥkha) and on emptiness (śūnya).

We reject these four types of meditation on the grounds that they lack scriptural support of the Vedas and the Upaniṣads (aprāmāṇikatvāt). They are ineffective practices because the objects of meditation are wrong.  Proper object of meditation is the Lord alone.

> I know the great Purusha, who is luminous, like the sun and beyond
> darkness. Only by knowing Him does one pass over death; there is no
> other way to the Supreme Goal. (Svetasvatara Upanishad 3.8)
>
> The Blessed Lord said: Those who fix their minds on Me and always
> engage in My devotion with steadfast faith, I consider them to be the
> best yogis.(BG 12.2)
>
> There are those who always think of Me and engage in exclusive
> devotion to Me. To them, whose minds are always absorbed in Me, I
> provide what they lack and preserve what they already possess. (BG
> 9.22)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. There are three points given.                        

1. Can't explain the cause of universe
2. Can't explain the causation
3. Goal is not desirable

Comment: 1. Now regarding creation and cause of the universe. This exception maybe just maybe valid like 2 thousand years ago but no more. Given that what we know of Big bang theory and Evolution we need no active agent to "create" universe. It can come about itself with no one that needs to be put together.

Comment: 2. Regarding causation: There is an assumption that the single moment of cause and effect are synchronous. There is an assumption of universal objective frame of time. This was proved wrong by Einstein. The cause and effect even though momentary can influence each other because their moments over lap. And in that overlap causation happens. The beginning and end of moments of cause and effect are not same. So even this is objection is wrong

Comment: 3. Goal of Buddhism: Here its said that Buddhism advocates destruction of self. Quite the contrary. Buddhism does not say to destroy the self but says that there is no self, and the self that is experienced is an illusion which is causing the suffering. According to Buddhism there is no self so, how can one advocate to destroy it? It only advocates to conquer the illusion of the self. More over regarding no backing of the scriptures. Its an argument in circular. Why should Vedas backup Buddhism. Why Vedas backing up proof of anything? Also how are Vedas proved. So even this objection is wrong.

Comment: 1) Nope. The recognition of the subjective experiential state as the ultimate reality is based on logic and experience.

Comment: Please come to chat room

Comment: 2)What Buddhism says is nothing is real/created or born. All the external appearances are untrue. Nothing exist for more than a moment. Their source of knowledge is not permanent but keeps changing. What was true a second before, is not true now.
I may say that Buddhist philosophy was true a second before, not now. If you say that there is nothing, then who is the observer to ensure that there is nothing? Certainly there is something that is not untrue, which observes the untrue.

Comment: Where ? Provide the link please

Comment: 1)  what?? we are talking about creation without agent. What has the subjective element got to do with  anything

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118962/discussion-between-sethu-srivatsa-koduru-and-varun-n-rao).

Comment: I agree with Sethu if Buddhism says I am an illusion what point is there to attain moksha or even to be myself? I may as well pursuit worldly pleasures if there is no me. The self teaches within us a fundamental nature contrasting us from random objects we find and to realize that nature is static to attain a greater bliss and union with the greatest seer.

Comment: As for regarding creationism and a creative agent keep in mind many texts see god in a more deistic or cosmological light. Also, nature does need intelligence behind it to function plain and simple. That's why there are laws in nature. The fact that this world is so complex gives credence to this idea. If the world after all is simply a complex machine without machinists, then it would be able to only expound beings similar to its nature. The fact that we are more than mere machines or computers there is something that makes us an observer disproves your argument.

Comment: I do think it is dangerous to deny science which is based on perception and inference, rather we should interpret these natural laws to coincide with scripture so their is no contradiction.

Comment: The issue with Buddhism for me is deny, deny, deny and nothing is real. For us, it's reinterpret, reform, recreate, and only otherwise refute.

Comment: @Haridasa No Buddhism doesn't denies, **nothing is real**, it rather says, **nothing is actually real** and everything is based on **nothing** (shunya). Also, **shunya** doesn't implies absence of matter and silence, it rather implies **something** that is independent of [*chatuskoti*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catu%E1%B9%A3ko%E1%B9%ADi). It is a **logical void** and NOT a **physical one!**.

Comment: @User29449 so existence itself is based on nothingness that makes 0 sense

Comment: @Haridasa No. This is wrong, Existence is based on **shunya** and not nothingness. See *MoolmadhyamikaKarika*, where Nagajurna contradicts the existence of Nothingness.

Comment: @User29449 if the world has logical absence, then there cannot be rules attributed to nature, nor could the world produce logical beings.

Comment: @Haridasa Madhya = Middle path. Buddhism when they talk about void, or shunya, they mean a reality that is middle to all possible realities of the universe. It doesn't mean emptiness, silence, or logical absence. It just means, we logically find the middle most path of all possibilities and meditate on it.

Comment: @User29449 But, that's a limitation and not one based on reason. The middle of all things wouldn't lead to salvation. It would be the highest.

Comment: @Haridasa Why middle things wouldn't lead to salvation? Bhagavad Gita clearly states that those people who maintain equanimity in all situations, without getting affected with dualities are in perfect yog. Chatuskoti establishes a logical shunya to meditate that is the middle path of all possibilities, hence dualities become same for the meditator.